# Issue deploying loopback to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, loopback

I had no issues previously deploying to heroku but a few push's to master later I began to see this error in the terminal when i did git push heroku master:

```
remote: 400557 silly vacuum-fs removing /tmp/build_73cfd27afe73fd280337c3fd2cd3c9bf/vendor/node/bin/slc
remote: 400558 silly vacuum-fs quitting because other entries in /tmp/build_73cfd27afe73fd280337c3fd2cd3c9bf/vendor/node/bin
remote: 400559 info postuninstall strongloop@6.0.1
remote: 400560 silly gentlyRm /tmp/build_73cfd27afe73fd280337c3fd2cd3c9bf/vendor/node/lib/node_modules/strongloop is being purged from base /tmp/build_73cfd27afe73fd280337c3fd2cd3c9bf/vendor/node
remote: 400561 verbose gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking /tmp/build_73cfd27afe73fd280337c3fd2cd3c9bf/vendor/node/lib/node_modules/strongloop
remote: 400562 silly vacuum-fs purging /tmp/build_73cfd27afe73fd280337c3fd2cd3c9bf/vendor/node/lib/node_modules/strongloop
remote: 400563 silly vacuum-fs quitting because other entries in /tmp/build_73cfd27afe73fd280337c3fd2cd3c9bf/vendor/node/lib/node_modules
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to myapp.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git'
```

here is my Procfile:

```
web: slc run
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node .",
    "pretest": "eslint .",
    "posttest": "nsp check"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async-series": "0.0.1",
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.5.2",
    "helmet": "^1.3.0",
    "loopback": "^2.22.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.6.5",
    "loopback-component-explorer": "^2.4.0",
    "loopback-connector-mongodb": "^1.15.2",
    "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^2.39.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1",
    "strong-error-handler": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^2.5.3",
    "nsp": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "description": "myapp"
}
```

when I run heroku logs I receive some memory issue, Im not sure if this is related to my problem:

```
2016-09-05T19:23:21.380834+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=935M(182.8%)
2016-09-05T19:23:21.380938+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2016-09-05T19:23:42.483862+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=936M(183.0%)
2016-09-05T19:23:42.483938+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2016-09-05T19:24:03.606013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=936M(182.8%)
2016-09-05T19:24:03.606059+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

WHAT I TRIED:

1. I have since reset my commits back to the point where I was able to push to heroku. Doing that did nothing. I still get the same error with my previous working code.
2. I have also temporarily upgraded my plan from hobby to the higher performance plans. This got rid of the memory leak warnings when I ran heroku logs but I still could not push to heroku. I received the same error given above.
3. I also tried restarting my dynos. Again no changes :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issues. I'm using a project that I've deployed dozens of times, and this just started today. Looks like it might be something on Heroku's end. Did you happen to find a fix yet?

UPDATE: Found a fix! I had the exact error as the answer below:

```
remote: 399727 error path /tmp/build_2b4a4006d967fde144d63244a50616b8/vendor/node/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-sdk-angular-cli/bin/lb-ng
```

I had read today on Heroku to always save your build tools in your dependencies in package.json and remembered mine is installed globally, so I ran this command:

```
npm install --save loopback-sdk-angular-cli
```

Then, I pushed it to Heroku, and it finally went through.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard back from heroku and they told me to contact the third party buildpack creators. In this case strongloop. I sent them an email. I am waiting to hear back. If I find a solution I will post here. If you guys have any luck please do the same!

Answer (score 0):

```
"engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x"
  },
```

I changed to

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8.0.x"
  },
```

and it worked. maybe try using latest node version.